# Get directory mtime when file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the `mtime` on a directory. I am not sure if this is the correct way, but how can I get the `mtime` when a file within the directory changes?

This is currently what I am doing:

```
let statTs = fs.statSync(cfgDir);
```

I am then later checking that time vs another directory or file's time to decide if I need to run a build command:

```
if (!statJs || (statTs && statJs && statTs.mtime > statJs.mtime)) {
    cp.execSync(`${tscPath} -p "${configFile}"`);
}
```

If I dump the `mtime` of the `statTs`:

```
console.log(statTs.mtime)
```

I always get the same time even if I modify the file within the directory. Is there a way to get that time when a file changes?

I am using a windows machine, so maybe this works differently on different operating systems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found was to glob all the files and get the latest changed time like so:

```
private getDirMtime(dirpath) {
    let stat = fs.statSync(dirpath)
    if(stat.isFile()){ return Promise.resolve(stat.mtime) }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let lastMod = new Date(1970, 0)
        glob(path.join(dirpath, '**/*.*'), files => {
            files.forEach(file => {
                let stat = fs.statSync(file)
                if(stat.isFile() && stat.mtime > lastMod) {
                    lastMod = stat.mtime
                }
            })
            return resolve(lastMod)
        })
    })
}
```